# Inverse function and integrals restrictly in an interval.

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, inverse-function

I'm having difficults to write formally the first two items could someone show me a formal proof of both. about the last item i have no idea how to start it. I don't know the concept of continuity either derivability so doesn't make sense for me using they to proof it, any suggestion? Question bellow:

Consider $f:[p,q] \to \mathbb{R}$ a strictly increasing function whose image is the interval $[\gamma , \theta]$.

$i)$ Prove that $\gamma = f(p) \ ,\ \theta = f (q)$ and that $f$ is a bijective fuction from $[p,q]$ to $[\gamma, \theta]$.

$ii)$ Prove that $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing.

$iii)$ For $f(p) \ge 0$ and $f(p) \lt 0$ prove that:

$$\int_{\gamma}^{\theta} f^{-1}(x) dx\ = \ q\ f(q) - p\ f(p) - \int_{p}^{q} f(x) dx $$

Comment: How about you try to prove i) and ii) by contradiction?

Comment: ok! i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(i) and (ii) are straightforward and depend only on understanding the words "image" and "inceasing". How could $f(p)$ be smaller than $\gamma$?

For (iii) draw a   the graph of $f$ and put it in a rectangle.Think about how the graph of $f$ is related to the graph of its inverse.

Comment: ok, i think (iii) makes more sense now.

Comment: my result is $$ \int_{\gamma}^{\theta} f^{-1} (x) dx = qf(q) - qf(p) - \int_{p}^{q} f(x) dx$$. I made it 3 times and get this result, maybe the question is wrong or am i ?